# Android goto another fragment from dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I had created [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) in my application. Here is the code:

```
public static class SkipDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        OnClickListener {
    private Button btnYes;
    private Button btnCancel;
    //private PerformActionListener mListener;
    private AlertDialog ad;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //mListener = (PerformActionListener) getActivity();
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View customDialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog_alert_yes_no,
                null);
        TextView txtMessage = (TextView) customDialogView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        txtMessage.setText(getResources().getString(
                R.string.disagreement_stmt));
        btnYes = (Button) customDialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        btnYes.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnCancel = (Button) customDialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(
                customDialogView).create();
        return ad;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.equals(btnYes)) {
            new CreateProfileFragment().gotoHome();
            //mListener.onActionPerformed();
            ad.dismiss();
        }

        if (v.equals(btnCancel)) {
            ad.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

When the user clicks on Positive button in the dialog, it should navigate to another fragment. Here is the code for fragment to be displayed:

```
private void gotoHome() {
    HomeFragment homeFragment = (HomeFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.home_fragment);
    if (homeFragment != null) {
        homeFragment.initializeView();
    } else {
        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        transaction.replace(R.id.linFragmentContainer, homeFragment,
                AppUtils.HOME_FRAGMENT);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

But, whenever I click on Yes button in the dialog, [getFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager%28%29) in the gotoHome() returns null. I am not getting why is this happening.

Comment: try to call `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: use interface as a callback to the activity and replace the existing fragment in the container with a new one

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes, I am already using that. Just, not understanding why getFragmentManager() returns null when called directly from dialog fragment.

Comment: @Nitish where is the call back to the activity??

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes the callback is in activity. I had solved my problem by sending a localbroadcast from the callback. I am just curious to understand when I called to next fragment from the dialog fragment why getFragmentManager returned null.